# Array formula find the closes value in a row

Tags: sorting, if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I tried to convert this one to find the closest match in an array but, I do not think you can do it that way.

```
=VLOOKUP(a1,SORT(range,1,TRUE),2)

=ArrayFormula(iferror(VLOOKUP(Q2:Q,SORT(R2:S,1,TRUE),2),""))
```

Any other ideas on how to make an array formula which finds the closes value in a row?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1V00i3XlEx5Q2Xp0QZevS5o2pdpU2QNNNX5d8bkHtn3U/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ABS(B2:B-C2:C)<ABS(B2:B-D2:D), C2:C, D2:D))
```

[image]

---

for multiple columns:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
 IF(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(ABS(B2:B-C2:G)), 
 "select "&TEXTJOIN(",", 1, "min(Col"&ROW(B2:B)-ROW(B2)+1&")")&"")), 
 "select Col2")=ABS(B2:B-C2:G), C2:G, )),,99^99))))
```

[image: 0]